# dotnet fuscator

Tags: asp.net, dotfuscator

I used Dotfuscator to protect my application from reverse engineering I encrepted the dll files and saved them, my question is what to do after that? how to use new dlls insted of old ones because when i do copy and past and after that I publish the website it get the old dlls not new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing your site via Visual Studio?  If so, it would seem that the obfuscated DLLs are somehow bypassed.  Are you overwriting the original DLLs with the obfuscated DLLs before publishing them?  As a last resort, use FTP to publish your site, as you can be sure which versions of DLLs you're uploading.

Comment: I replace the dlls before publishing them

Comment: It would seem Visual Studio is overwriting your obfuscated DLLs, then.  Try FTP instead.

Comment: Yes, Dotfuscator is not able to hook into the 'Publish' mechanism in Visual Studio - Publish will always publish your unobfuscated binaries. You'll need to manually upload the obfuscated binaries (or have a post-build batch file that does so).